# I tried to get data from combobox but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I using this code.. but nothing happen.. I already try to look for the solution but its still happening.. When I change the value from numericUpDown the PriceTxt.Text doesn't change.. I hope someone can explain me why this is happen and how to solve it.. I'm out of idea..

```
private void quantityTxt_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = this.DescTxt.GetItemText(this.DescTxt.SelectedItem);
            if (DescTxt.Text == "SET A -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR")
            {
                MessageBox.Show((5 * quantityTxt.Value).ToString());
                PriceTxt.Text = (5 * quantityTxt.Value).ToString();
            }
            else if (selected == "SET B -AYAM GORENG + NUGGETS + AIR")
            {
                MessageBox.Show((10 * quantityTxt.Value).ToString());
                PriceTxt.Text = (10 * quantityTxt.Value).ToString();
            }
            else if (selected == "SET C -AYAM GORENG + MEATBALL + AIR")
            {
                MessageBox.Show((15 * quantityTxt.Value).ToString());
                PriceTxt.Text = (15 * quantityTxt.Value).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good day to learn to use the debugger.  Put a stop on that first line and when it hits it, step through the code line by line, examine the values by hovering your mouse over the variables.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to use `this.` every time to access the controls in your form.

Comment: I think `ValueChanged` only fires if you have a DataSource with the `ValueMember` property set.  How did you populate the ComboBox?  If not using a data source, use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead.

Comment: Add `else { MessageBox.Show("No matches"); }` to check if none of the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it solves your issue?

```
// Form.Load event. Here ComboBox fills with some values
// and subscription to ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged event provided
private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] items = new[] 
   {
      "SET A -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR",
      "SET B -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR",
      "SET C -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR"
   };

   myComboBox.Items.AddRange(items);
   // Subscribe to SelectedValueChanged event
   myComboBox.SelectedValueChanged += OnSelectedValueChange;
}

// Our SelectedValueChanged handler
private void OnSelectedValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Getting content of new selected in ComboBox item
    string selectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int switchableValue; // Your 5, 10, 15

    // Check in proper way
    switch (selectedItem)
    {
       case "SET A -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR":
           switchableValue = 5;
           break;
       case "SET B -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR":
           switchableValue = 10;
           break;
       case "SET C -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR":
           switchableValue = 15;
           break;
       default:
           // Maybe reset some values if needed before return
           return;
    }
    
    // Get your neccesarry result value, converted to string through interpolation
    string someResult = $"{switchableValue * quantityTxt.Value}"; 

    // Do work with result value
    MessageBox.Show(someResult);
    PriceTxt.Text = someResult;
}
```

UPD:
My example handling ComboBox item change, not NumericUpDown value change (i'm blind guy at least).
If you need dependency on NumericUpDown control - you should change subscription to NumericUpDown.ValueChanged and add check for null ComboBox.SelectedItem value:

```
private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Still fill items up there...

   // Instead of ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged event subscription
   // myComboBox.SelectedValueChanged += OnSelectedValueChange;
   // Subscribe to NumericUpDown.ValueChanged event:
   quantityTxt.ValueChanged += OnQuantityValueChange;
}

private void OnQuantityValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add check for null to ComboBox.SelectedItem property
    // by appeding '?' at end of it
    string selectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedItem?.ToString();

    // .. rest of code is the same.
    // If ComboBox.SelectedItem would be null -
    // method would break in switch statement by 'default' behaviour.
}
```

Or you may combine both ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged and NumericUpDown.ValueChanged events to one handler:

```
private void OnDescTxtOrQuantityTxtChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedItem?.ToString();
    int switchableValue;

    switch (selectedItem)
    {
        case "SET A -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR":
            switchableValue = 5;
            break;
        case "SET B -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR":
            switchableValue = 10;
            break;
        case "SET C -AYAM GORENG + FRIES + AIR":
            switchableValue = 15;
            break;
        default:
            // MessageBox.Show("You didn't select Description!")
            return;
     }

     // Add check for NumericUpDown '0' value if needed, 
     // cuz multiplying 'switchableValue' (5/10/15) to 0 will result with 0
     if (quantityTxt.Value == 0)
     {
         // MessageBox.Show("You didn't select Quantity!")
         return;
     }

     string someOutput = $"{switchableValue * quantityTxt.Value}";

     MessageBox.Show(someOutput);
     PriceTxt.Text = someOutput;
}
```

And subscribe it on both events:

```
myComboBox.SelectedValueChanged += OnDescTxtOrQuantityTxtChange;
quantityTxt.ValueChanged += OnDescTxtOrQuantityTxtChange;
```

Comment: Edited post, because figured that I mistaken with event that you subsribe (think ComboBox change, in fact NumbericUpDown change).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
string selected = DescTxt.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

or

```
string selected = DescTxt.Text;
```

Comment: I already try that.. but it doesn't work.. n no error at all..

Comment: Ok, is quantityTxt a NumericUpDown control or a textbox? Seems the event isn't being fired.

Comment: quantityTxt is NumericUpDown and DescTxt is combobox

Comment: Is the event being fired? an easy way to check if the event is being fired - add `MessageBox.Show(selected);` right after `string selected = ..... ;`. If no MessageBox shows up when you are changing the NumericUpDown value, the event isn't being fired. If a MessageBox shows up with the combobox selected item, you can concisely work on the code itself.

Comment: I've trying that.. and when I did it.. the message box is pop up..

Comment: Ah, so the selected value of the ComboBox doesn't fit in any of the if-else conditions, please update them.